# Match Numeric value after comma separated, concatenated by underscore values using MYSQL/MariaDB & REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb

I have field column values stored like:

texta_123,textb_456

My SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE 456 = REGEXP_SUBSTR(mytable.concatenated_csv_values, 'textb_(?<number>[0-9]+)')
```

*NOTE: I'm aware there are multiple ways of doing this, but for the purposes of example I simplified my query substantially; the part I need to work is `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`*

Effectively, I want to: "query results where an id equals the numeric value extracted after an underscore in a column with comma-separated values"

When I [test my Regex](https://regex101.com/r/pWQY9r/1), it seems to work fine.

However, in MySQL (technically, I'm using MariaDB 10.4.19), when I run the query I get a warning: "Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value:textb_456"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should seriously consider fixing your database design to not store unnormalized CSV data like this.  As a temporary workaround, we can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` along with `FIND_IN_SET`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(
          '456',
          REGEXP_REPLACE(concatenated_csv_values, '^.*_', '')) > 0;
```

The regex trick used here would convert a CSV input of `texta_123,textb_456` to just `123,456`.  Then, we can easily search for a given ID using `FIND_IN_SET`.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That did the trick. Good point & well taken on the DB design, I plan to have a separate table that will take place of some the CSV data but needed an interim solution :)